# LiveView File Server unavailable error when test development ipa Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, ipa, liveview

My development platform iOS. My development SDK 5.1.0. I run into a strange error of [LiveView] Server unavailable while testing my app via development ipa on device. Before this i always made development ipa through Titanium Studio but due to some configuration problems of iOS sdk in Titanium Studio i switched to Appcelerator Studio. I am able to make development ipa successfully from Appcelerator Studio but when i install it on my device and run there is always error of LiveView server unavailable. Has anyone else faced this problem then do reply i have to send test build to my client for testing.[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjbzF.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have enabled LiveView for your app, which doesn't work if you manually install an IPA to your device.. you should disable LiveView!

It is the little green icon with the eye in Appcelerator Studio in the toolbar!

Comment: Please look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304560/how-to-use-theme-for-searchview-to-override-default-in-titanium please suggest me in this